# Replacing Unwrap()s with ? - compiler complaining on functions that do return Result or Option

Tags: rust

I'm only a few days into my Rust journey and going over my now functionally completed first project, working on [exercising](https://dmerej.info/blog/post/killing-unwrap/) `unwrap()`s from my code.

The first two instances I've tried, I've completely failed and I cannot work out why. I have this line in my code:

```rust
let json = str::from_utf8(&buf).unwrap();
```

`from_utf8` returns `Result<&str, Utf8Error>`, but trying:

```rust
let json = str::from_utf8(&buf)?;
```

Has a compiler error of *"This function should return Result or Option to accept ?"*, but it does return `Result`. I can only assume that the pointer `&` is having an effect here?

I've refactored this now to:

```rust
match str::from_utf8(&buf) {
    Ok(json) => {
        let msg: MyMessage = serde_json::from_str(json).unwrap();
        self.tx.try_send((msg, src)).expect("Could not send data");
    }
    Err(e) => {}
};
```

I still need to work out what to do in the `Err` but I've gotten rid of the `unwrap()` call. However, there's another.

```rust
serde_json::from_str(json).unwrap();
```

This returns `Result<T>`, so:

```rust
serde_json::from_str(json)?;
```

This is also complaining about the fact it should return `Result` when it already does.

At this point, it's safe to assuming I'm really confused and I don't understand half as much as a thought I did.

Countless blogs just say use `?`, yet, in every instances I think it should work and the return types appear suitable, the compiler says no.

Would the `From` trait work here? Is it common to have to write traits like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `from_utf8` returns `Result<&str, Utf8Error>`, but trying:
>
> ```rust
> let json = str::from_utf8(&buf)?;
> ```
>
> Has a compiler error of `This function should return Result or Option to accept ?`. But it does return `Result`.

*`This function`* here refers to the outer function. That is, the function you are writing, not `from_utf8`.

`?` will return an error from your function if there was one, thus *your* function needs the right return type to be able to return an error.

Because `from_utf8` is not the source of the issue, you'd get the same error like this too:

```rust
let r = Err(...);
let json = r?;
```

Comment: So obvious now you have pointed it out. But what if the outer method doesn't return anything intentionally? I'm going to update my question as this is really relevant to the solution. Thank you.

Comment: Actually I don't think I need too. `?` isn't going to work in my instance and I need to implement them all as `match` since this is a loop executing on a thread, it's kind of a `fire and forget` thread entry point with no return value.

Comment: @Jammer `?` isn't a shorthand for `unwrap`, which is what you seem to want. So it doesn't make sense to use it for that purpose.

Comment: Yeah, I've actually figured it all out now. Handling all the errors and ok;s. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Jammer It is also unlikely you need `match`. At least you don't need it for the examples you showed (unwrapping and ignoring errors).

Comment: Ahhh, OK. More food for thought!!

Answer (score 2):

The `?` operator is roughly equivalent to a match with an early return for the error case, so in your example

```
fn foo() {
    let json = str::from_utf8(&buf)?;
    // ...
}
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
fn foo() {
    let json = match str::from_utf8(&buf) {
        Ok(j) => j,
        Err(e) => return Err(e.into()),
    }
    // ...
}
```

This should make it clear where the error is coming from. You are trying to return a `Result` from a function that doesn't return anything.